# linkedin Api : how can I use a value stored in a variable to post network update

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, linkedin-api

I have a string variable ... I want the value stored in this variable to be posted as network update in LinkedIn .....

can someone guide me how can I modify the code below to achieve this functionality..

```
updateURL = "/people/~/person-activities"
IN.API.Raw(updateURL)
  .method("POST")
  .body('{"contentType":"linkedin-html","body":"my nw update"}')
  .result(function(result) {
      alert ("Updated");
  })
  .error( function(error) { console.log(error); })
```

Right now it posts "my new update".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.Stringify all you need to place here as [linkedin](http://developer.linkedin.com/message/9804#9804) api supports json, so u just need to convert your variable into json string.

```
IN.API.Raw("/people/~/current-status") // Update (PUT) the status
.method("PUT")
.body(JSON.stringify(urvariablehere))
.result( function(result) { document.getElementById("statusDiv").innerHTML = "Status updated"; } )
.error(  function(error)  { /* do nothing */ } );
```

Comment: hi 

what does this do

IN.API.Raw("/people/~/current-status")

Comment: glad it helped!, and that snippet is taken from linkedin site, u can check the link. and it put the users current status on wall(status updates).